# Symfony2 translatable doesn't use joins

Tags: symfony, translation

I use translatable and now my page has 133 db queries because symfony retrieves every translation separate. How can I make it do a join when fetching entities?

Answer (score 0):

You should use query hint to do the join before..
https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/translatable.md#using-orm-query-hint

However maybe its better not to use translatable sometimes ...